# Nancy : Razor View Engine: Is the _ViewStart file supported?

Tags: razor, nancy

Can you tell me if the special Razor file **_ViewStart.cshtml** is supported in Nancy? I know it was scheduled for inclusion ([here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nancy-web-framework/X0sYTPuaR-U)). Can you tell me if it is now available please? It is not currently working for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Support for that has not been built in (yet). The upcoming 0.11 release will contains @helper functions and better HtmlHelpers extensibility

Answer (score 3):

**Breaking News**

_ViewStart is now supported as of Nancy version 0.20